# Create Row_Number in linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query which I wish to replace with a Linq as query syntax. Below is my SQL query which I'm trying to create I've got it all working except the row_number:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ID, 
    r.StateProvinceRegion,  
    AVG(s.Longitude) AS Longitude, 
    AVG(s.Latitude) AS Latitude
FROM
    RestaurantAddress r 
INNER JOIN 
    Restaurant s ON s.RestaurantId = r.RestaurantId
GROUP BY
    StateProvinceRegion
```

Query result:

```
ID  StateRegion  Longitude           Latitude
-----------------------------------------------------
1   Auckland     174.759541622222    -36.8552809611111
2   Mumbai       -73.9904097          40.7036292
3   New York     -73.9904097          40.7036292
```

This is the current code I've implemented which has the same output except doesn't have the `ROW_NUMBER (ID)` which I'm trying to figure out how to output.

```
var region = from restaurantAddress in _context.RestaurantAddress
             join restaurant in _context.Restaurant on restaurantAddress.RestaurantId equals restaurant.RestaurantId
             group restaurant by new { restaurantAddress.StateProvinceRegion } into g
             select new { g.Key.StateProvinceRegion, Latitude = g.Average(p => p.Latitude), Longitude = g.Average(p => p.Longitude) };
```

This is what I've tried:

```
 int number = 0; 
 var region = from restaurantAddress in _context.RestaurantAddress
             join restaurant in _context.Restaurant on restaurantAddress.RestaurantId equals restaurant.RestaurantId
             group restaurant by new { restaurantAddress.StateProvinceRegion } into g
             select new { id = number++ , g.Key.StateProvinceRegion, Latitude = g.Average(p => p.Latitude), Longitude = g.Average(p => p.Longitude) };
```

but `number++` returns an error:

> An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator

Comment: You can do that client side like `query.AsEnumerable().Select((x,i) => new { Stuff = x, Index = i});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple:

```
var region =
    (
        from restaurantAddress in _context.RestaurantAddress
        join restaurant in _context.Restaurant
            on restaurantAddress.RestaurantId equals restaurant.RestaurantId
        group restaurant by new { restaurantAddress.StateProvinceRegion } into g
        select new
        {
            g.Key.StateProvinceRegion,
            Latitude = g.Average(p => p.Latitude),
            Longitude = g.Average(p => p.Longitude),
        }
    )
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select((x, id) => new
        {
            id,
            x.StateProvinceRegion,
            x.Latitude,
            x.Longitude,
        });
```

Comment: Better to use an `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToArray` and I'm 99% sure that overload of `Select` is not supported by EF.  Also more efficient to select the required values especially the averages before bringing the query client side.

Comment: Why is `AsEnumerable` better than `ToArray`?

Comment: @juharr - Done.

Comment: `AsEnumerable` will not create an unneeded intermediate collection, also it allows the DB query to be deferred until it's actually iterated.

Comment: Would the ID be starting at 0? or 1?

Comment: @rey123 - it's easy to test, but it would be `0`.